# Looking for a generalization of Binomial distribution and its properties

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I asked this on MathOverflow, but was redirected here.

In my research (coming from computer science), I have encountered a family of discrete probability distributions that seems to be some sort of generalization of the binomial distribution. A distribution in this family has a parameter $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and parameters $p_{0}, \ldots ,p_{n-1} \in [0,1]$. The distribution has $n+1$ possible values.

Denote the respective probabilities $q_0,\ldots,q_n$. So far, I have managed to obtain the descriptions for the first few $n$, which are the following:

- If $n=1$, the distribution is: \begin{align*}q_0 =& 1-p_0\\q_1 =& 1-q_0\end{align*}
- If $n=2$, the distribution is: \begin{align*}q_0=&(p_0-1)^2\\ q_1=&(p_0-1)p_0(p_1-1)\\ q_2 =& 1-q_0-q_1\end{align*}
- If $n=3$, the distribution is: \begin{align*}q_0=&(1 - p_0)^3\\q_1 =& 3 (p_0-1)^2 p_0 (p_1-1)^2 \\ q_2=& -3 (p_0-1) p_0 (p_1-1)^2 (2 (p_0-1) p_1-p_0) (p_2-1)\\q_3 =& 1-q_0-q_1-q_2 \end{align*}

I could give the descriptions for few higher $n$, but it becomes lots of symbols quickly.

I have noticed, that when I set $p_i = 0 \; \forall i = 1,...,n-1$ it degenerates to the distribution $\mathrm{Bin}(n,p_0)$. I have several goals with this.

First, I wanted to ask if this resembles some well known distribution family generalizing the binomial distribution? Can anyone suggest possible general formulas that would produce $q_i$ for a given $n$?

Second, assuming we have a generalization, what would be the measure of all the distributions representable as a member of this family for given $n$ or some upper bound of such measure? Denoting this measure $l_n$, I have computed that: $$\begin{aligned} l_1 &= \sqrt{2}, &l_2 &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, & l_3 &= \frac{27}{280}, & l_4 &=\frac{73162}{5010005\sqrt{5}} \end{aligned}$$.

Comment: Can you describe exactly the sampling process you are referring to? Right now, you haven't, and we are left to figure out how the distribution you're considering is even defined.

Comment: It's somewhat complicated and I didn't want to go into the details. I was mostly just hoping this could resemble something well known to give me some hints where to look.

Comment: Without those details, this is more like a shot in the dark than anything else....